# How to figure out why rendering base.html is very slow in production (on Heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've had a Django app running on Heroku for a few months without issue. Out of nowhere, it's become extremely slow/non-responsive and is taking a ton of memory.

New Relic cryptically tells me that 98% of the load time is "Application code (in Render/base.html)" but doesn't tell me anything else. So far as I know, we haven't changed anything in base.html that would cause it to behave differently.

Anyone else come across this issue? How do I troubleshoot it/get to the bottom of it?

Thank you!

**UPDATE** -- I can no longer push changes to Heroku. It stalls either at "Cleaning up..." or "Collecting static files" before it times out (Heroku kills compilation if it takes longer than 15 minutes).

Comment: did you change anything that can affect the HTML rendering? other templates, view code, static files?

Comment: Fair question -- I have made a number of changes, but none seem like they should have any effect (i.e., changing the wording). It seems like it isn't view-specific, since it effects literally every page (they all use base.html). Would love to hear if anyone has come across this and has figured out how to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: and it happens only on heroku? if you take the same code and run it with production settings (debug=false most important) it works just fine?

Comment: Yes, with DEBUG=False it worked fine on the development server. The problems were those specified below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not sure if I completely understand the root cause of the issue, but I solved the symptoms, and I wanted to post here so that anyone else coming across the same issue needs help.

There were two separate problems happening at the same time.

First, I was running too many gunicorn workers on each dyno. They gobbled up a lot of RAM (for reasons I do not know still -- Heroku is a bit of a black box) and slowed everything down. Changing my Procfile so that it's only one gunicorn worker per dyno solved that problem, at least for now.

My Procfile now looks like:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn myapp.wsgi --workers=1 --timeout=25
```

Second, it turned out my s3 bucket was full of > 100k JavaScripts my app was automatically producing (I am using a tool called django_compressor), and when Heroku ran collectstatic during the deploy, it tried to check if anything on s3 had changed, requiring it to iterate over 100k files. This caused timeouts to occur every time I tried to push a new deploy to Heroku.

django_compressor caused this because I had accidentally included in base.html a block for additional JavaScripts inside the {% compress js %} tags.

DON'T DO THIS:

```
{% compress js %}
<script src="..." />
<script src="..." />
{% block additionaljs %}{% endblock %} <--- BAD -- should be outside of the {% compress %} tags
{% endcompress %}
```

Comment: yea this was the first thing I thought about.. next time explain the changes you did better and get a better answer ;)